# FieldInfo setValue with object array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
int classNode = 0;

foreach ( XmlNode element in tempClassAll )
{
    foreach ( XmlNode item in element )
    {
        content[ classNode ] = new TemplateClass();
        FieldInfo tempField = targetClass.GetField( item.Name );
        tempField.SetValue( content[classNode],
                            Convert.ChangeType( item.InnerText,tempField.FieldType ) );

        Debug.Log( tempField.Name +
                   "     " +
                   tempField.GetValue( content[ classNode ] ) );
    }

    classNode++;
}

foreach (var item in content)
{
    Debug.Log(item.JobID);
}
```

The first `Debug.Log` can print the value in `content[]`，but the second cannot.
This is really a strange problem.  Thanks for any idea.

Comment: explain what happens when the second Debug.Log is executed?

Comment: print all object's "JobID" field.The first Debug.Log can print all field's value in object.the JobID Filed should have values but all second Debug print 0